# Next.js production mode public folder can't access dynamically

Tags: next.js

I have a running Next.js application. In the development mode, I am able to access public folder files dynamically but in production mode, I'm not able to access them dynamically.

I can access only the previous files before build time.

- Next.js v12
- Node v16.13
- OS Windows 11